# Generate numerically stable equation automatically

Tags: numerics, stability, numerical-limitations

I remember there is a software (and its website interface) that can generate numerically stable equation from an expression automatically.

To see the problem it tries to solve, let’s take a look at a simple example of $f(x) = \log(1 + \exp(x))$.
If $x$ is a relatively large number (e.g. 800), $\exp(x)$ could be very large and reach `inf` in the floating point representation.
So it is better to split how to compute the function: (1) if $x < a$ (say $a = 50$), then it computes $f(x) = \log(1 + \exp(x))$ directly, (2) if $x \geq a$, then it computes $f(x) = x$.
The software I mention in the previous paragraph can automatically generate such equation splitting.

My question is: how does it (the software) work? And if you can put the reference to the website, it would be even better.
Thanks!

Comment: Could it be [herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org/)?

Comment: Yes! that's what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: I have *tried* herbie quite a few times now and compared its solutions to ones I worked out myself by hand. While it has improved over the years (e.g. it knows about FMA = fused multiply-add now) I recall no case where its solution was superior to the manually derived one, and only a few where the quality was on par. It is certainly superior to a do-nothing approach, and provides a solution in a few seconds, but is by no means an automatic cure all.